# Get rid of multicolumn effect

Tags: two-column

How to get rid of 2 columns and have a single column in this code?

```latex
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}

\title{Example of an APA style for journal article}
\shorttitle{APA style}

\twoauthors{Author One}{Author Two}
\twoaffiliations{Institute of Psychology}{Freud's Institute}

\abstract{This is an example of a journal article using the \texttt{apa6.cls} document class to typeset manuscripts according to 6th edition of the Americal Psychological Association (APA) manual}

\rightheader{APA style}
\leftheader{Author One}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle    

    \section{Sample section}
    Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. 
    Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. 
    Sample text. Sample text. Citation of Einstein paper~\cite{Einstein}. Citation of Freud book~\cite{Freud}.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    \subsection{Sample subsection}
    Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. 
    Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. 

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    \subsubsection{Sample subsubsection}
    Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. 
    Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. 


    Results are presented in Table~\ref{tab1}.
    \begin{table}[!htb]
        \caption{Sample table.}\label{tab1}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \hline\\[-1.5ex]
            AAA & BBB & CCC \\[0.5ex]
            \hline\\[-1.5ex]
            1.0 & 2.0 & 3.0\\[0.5ex]
            1.0 & 2.0 & 3.0\\[0.5ex]
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}


    \bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code screenshots.

Comment: sure. thanks. i'll edit it

Comment: you should only use a publisher class such as apa6 if submitting to the journal in which case the layout for the journal is fixed, you can't submit a single column article to a two column journal. that said adding `onecolumn` to the document class options might work...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the comment. I did try onecolumn in the document class but didn't work. Anyhow, in my document, I need to have a single column and also at the same time, I need the citations to be done in APA style. Is there any document class template file I can download? Please share the link if possible

Comment: you don't need to format your entire document as an APA journal submission just to format citations in a particular style. You could just use a standard `article` class.

Comment: apa6.cls looks like it uses `\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}`

Comment: Do you need a single column for the whole article, or just the table?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I need a single column to the whole document